# Scroll positions to last point for large view

Tags: android

I created my ruler like below using custom view and custom scrollerView.

My Custom RulerView is much longer in height. To handle it's current position I extended ScrollView and created my CustomScrollView.

But my issue is in S4 (android version 4.3) device it automatically scroll down to bottom position. Where as it works fine with S Duos (android version 4.0.4)

[image]